# How to shade all the cells that will be useless when you click on them?

Tags: python, pygame, grid

I made a little game *(Puzzling StackExchange helper)* using Pygame.

Here is a demonstration as to how it works:

[image]

If you can't tell, the program allows the user to select 2 adjacent cells, and then the number in the
two cells with be distributed evenly among the two cells. If the sum of the two numbers are odd,
the cell with the largest number in the first place will be one number greater than the other.

When the user first selects a cell, only the adjacent cells that have at least a difference of 2 from that cell will be highlighted.

I want to know how to give all the cells that **don't** have any adjacent cells with numbers at least a difference of 2 from that cell a shade of grey.

In other words, how to shade the cells that when you click on them, there will be no adjacent cell that you can click to change its number.

My code (scroll all the way down to see the comments, the way I attempted to make it work but failed):

```
import pygame

# You can change the grid & size to whatever you like
grid = [[7, 24, 12, 8, 11],
        [13, 21, 3, 20, 19],
        [10, 22, 15, 2, 9],
        [23, 1, 6, 16, 17],
        [5, 25, 14, 4, 18]]

size = 60

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", size-10)
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

class Square():
    def __init__(self, pos, num):
        self.x = pos[0] * size
        self.y = pos[1] * size
        self.num = num
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, size-5, size-5)

    def clear(self):
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
    
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(wn, self.color, self.rect)
        text = font.render(str(self.num), True, (0, 0, 0))
        if len(str(self.num)) == 1:
            wn.blit(text, (self.x+size*.25, self.y*.98))
        else:
            wn.blit(text, (self.x+size*.055, self.y*.98))
        


class Box():

    def __init__(self, grid, square=None):
        self.square = square
        self.grid = grid
        self.clicked = []

    def box(self): # Returns a list of all adjancent squares that can change the number of the selected square
        x, y = self.square.x//size, self.square.y//size
        y1 = x-1 if x else 0
        y2 = len(self.grid)+2 if x > len(self.grid)+2 else x+2
        x1 = y-1 if y else 0
        x2 = len(self.grid[0])+2 if y > len(self.grid[0])+2 else y+2
        b = []
        for r in self.grid[y1:y2]:
            for c in r[x1:x2]:
                if abs(c.num - self.grid[x][y].num) > 1:
                    b.append(c)
                elif c != self.square:
                    c.clear()
        return b

    def color(self, color):
        for square in self.box():
            square.color = color

    def clear(self):
        for c in self.clicked:
            c.clear()
        self.clicked.clear()

def avg(n1, n2):
    n = n1 + n2
    if n % 2:
        if n1 > n2:
            return n // 2 + 1, n // 2
        return n // 2, n // 2 + 1
    return n // 2, n // 2


squares = [[Square((i, j), col) for j, col in enumerate(row)] for i, row in enumerate(grid)]
box = Box(squares)
box2 = Box(squares)
total = 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for row in squares:
                for square in row:
                    if square.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                        if not box.clicked:
                            box.clicked.append(square)
                            square.color = (140, 255, 255)
                            box.square = square
                            box.color((255, 255, 140))
                        else:
                            if square in box.box():
                                box.clicked.append(square)
                            if square == box.clicked[0]:
                                box.color((255, 255, 255))
                                box.clear()
                        if len(box.clicked) == 2:
                            total += 1
                            print(total)
                            box.clicked[0].num, box.clicked[1].num = avg(box.clicked[0].num, box.clicked[1].num)
                            box.color((255, 255, 255))
                            box.clear()

    for row in squares:
        for square in row:
#            temp = Box(squares, square)
#            if not temp.box():
#                square.color = (140, 140, 140)
#            del(temp)
            square.draw()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: for every adjacent cell that does not match criteria do not light up in other words check each adjacent cell and if it meats condition light up

Comment: @Matiiss Actually, for every adjacent cell that does match criteria do not light up in other words check each adjacent cell and if it meats condition light up.

Comment: @Matiiss The criteria is that if we click on a square, no adjacent square will turn yellow.

Comment: In other words, how to shade the cells that when you click on them, there will be no adjacent cell that you can click to change its number. so every time player clicks and at the start check all cells and determine which ones are supposed to be in shadows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through all cells of the grid using nested loops and the indexes (*i*, *j*):

```py
for i in range(len(squares)):
    for j in range(len(squares[i])):
        # [...]
```

Find all the adjacent index tuples (*l*, *k*) of a cell (*i*, *j*):

```py
adjacent = []
for k in range(max(0,i-1), min(len(squares), i+2)):
    for l in range(max(0,j-1), min(len(squares[k]), j+2)):
        if i != k or j != l:
            adjacent.append((k, l))
```

Change the color of a cell if a cell (*i*, *j*) doesn't have a neighbor (`not any()`) (*l*, *k*) where the difference is at least 2:

```py
if not any((k, l) for (k, l) in adjacent if abs(squares[i][j].num - squares[k][l].num) > 1):
    squares[i][j].color = (140, 140, 140)
```

Complete nested loop

[image]

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    for i in range(len(squares)):
        for j in range(len(squares[i])):

            adjacent = []
            for k in range(max(0,i-1), min(len(squares), i+2)):
                for l in range(max(0,j-1), min(len(squares[k]), j+2)):
                    if i != k or j != l:
                        adjacent.append((k, l))

            if not any((k, l) for (k, l) in adjacent if abs(squares[i][j].num - squares[k][l].num) > 1):
                 squares[i][j].color = (140, 140, 140)
            elif squares[i][j].color == (140, 140, 140):
                square.clear()

    for row in squares:
        for square in row:
            square.draw()

    # [...]
```